# How INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY works?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with a table (let's call it `mytable`) which has 59 columns. The first column, called `id`, is set as an `INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY`. When it's time to insert new values, I'm executing `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (...)` where `(...)` is a sequence with **58** values. Why **58**? Because I guess that the `Id`value will increase automatically. But I get the error "table mytable has 59 columns but 58 values were supplied".

So how I need to execute my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let the `INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY` field autoincrement I need to set it to `NULL`, then SQLite will take care about everything else.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the columns you are adding if you are not adding all of them.

```
INSERT INTO table_name
  (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES 
  (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: Thanks. That could be a solution, let me check out other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to *guess* related to your PK identity spec.  Is the INT an IDENTITY?  If not then you will have to provide a value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but SQLite Browser doesn't have an IDENTITY option.

Comment: then you have your answer.

Comment: @TMcKeown SQLite has [`ROWID` and `AUTOINCREMENT`](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) so I don't see how IDENTITY fits here. That's SQL-Server terminology for the similar feature.

Comment: yes, i'm not a SQLite person, i think understanding it's an equivalent feature is adequate.